# How to initialize my app when calling a certain number

Tags: java, android

So I am likely the most newbie you could think of for Android Development. I have a basic knowledge of programming and basically by watching a youtube video i made an app the displays your location on your screen in the `mainActivity.java`. Now i want that app to open up when i call a number and i want it to work even after i restart my device. I have looked up many tutorials and its hard for me to understand and follow through about how it works. So i need really specific things like where specifically to place code in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and/or where specifically to place stuff in the main class or if i have to make a new class. Sorry if i am being to picky. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: I just have to warn you that you may not be able to legally do this.  I worked for a company named SnapIn Software in 2008-2010 timeframe.  They owned a patent on launching an app in response to dialing a number.  That patent is now owned by their successor company, Nuance Communications.  While I'm not a lawyer you may be opening yourself up to patent liability.  patent #7,353,016   http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20080401006204/en/SNAPin-Software-Awarded-U.S.-Patent-Call-Intercept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android apps listen for external events by using a combination of `Intents`, `Intent Filters` and `Broadcast Receivers`, you should read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Specifically for your use case, you need to listen to an event called `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` which is broadcasted by the Android system when the user makes a new call.

In order to do that, you must register your app to listen to this specific event and create a BroadcastReceiver class to handle it.

Your broadcast receiver will look somewhat like this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.d("OutgoingCallReceiver",phonenumber);
            Log.d("OutgoingCallReceiver",intent.getExtras().toString());
        }
}
```

And your Manifest will have to declare this receiver and register the event it listens:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Since handlig phone calls can be dangerous, you will also need to register your app Manifest to use a new permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

You can read more about it [here](https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1151).